# How to display model attributes in django on web app

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a portfolio site with djnago. Now suppose i have a blog and i want to show the blog title,small summary and the link. I've created a model as below:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    summary=models.TextField(blank=False)
    blogLink=models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
    def get_summary(self):
        return self.summary
    def get_link(self):
        return self.blogLink
```

I can fill these values in the admin page but how can i show it in the web app so that other people can access the links.
I also have a context processor to user details like first name etc. Should i have different context processors for  different classes that I create. Just a beginner and trying out projects to skill myself
I

Comment: I would suggest following the Django tutorial from part 3 onwards, this deals with views and templates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a `view` to query for a blog entry and send it to the front end.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls.models import Blog

def my_blog_detail_view(request, some_id):
    try:
        q = Blog.objects.get(pk=some_id)
    except Blog.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render(request, 'blog/my_blog_article.html', {'blog': q})
```

and set a path in your `urls.py`

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<int:some_id>/', views.my_blog_detail_view),
]
```

And you have also to write a Template. For in this example above `my_blog_article.html`.

You may rather look on YouTube or in the Django Documentation for a Tutorial on your first views and templates.

Also with reference to`blogLink=models.URLField()`. I do not know if this bloglink is for the blog in your Django Project or a link to a external Blog. If this is for your Django Project  you should use a `date` and `slug` (title) field in your model and later as a link.  So later on your site the link would look like this `www.mysite.xy/blog/2022/07/14/my-first-article`  see [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your answer. I did some exploration and found the answer to the ques.I do know about views and templates and I am in the process of creating them. Frontend is part that i can work on. blogLink=models.URLField() this does link to an external blog. Actually this project is like a digital resume, so every URLfield that I will create will link to an external site.